# Hibernate Criteria не срабатывает eqOrIsNull

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

Имеется простой участок кода,

```
public List<Department> getDepartmentBy(Account account)
{
    return createCriteria(Department.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("account ", account))
            .add(Restrictions.eqOrIsNull("archive", false))
            .list();
}
```

Без строки с `eqOrIsNull` выдает 8 записей, при этом во всех стоит `archive` `null` в БД.

Сам класс

```
private Account _account;
private boolean _archive = false;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "account_l", nullable = false)
public Account getAccount ()
{
    return _account;
}

public void setAccount(Account account)
{
    _account = account;
}

@Column(name = "archive_p")
public boolean isArchive()
{
    return _archive;
}

public void setArchive(boolean archive)
{
    _archive = archive;
}
```

Правильно ли я понял метод, что он должен давать нулевые записи или те, которые равные моему `false`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из [документации](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#eqOrIsNull-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-):

> Apply an "equal" constraint to the named property. If the value is
>   null, instead apply "is null".

Это означает, что `is null` будет использован только, если полученное значение является `null`. Во всех остальных случаях будет использоваться `equal` и сравнение с указанным значением, в вашем случае это `false`.

Не работает, скорее всего, из-за того, что вы используете примитивный тип `boolean`, который не может быть `null`. Поменяйте ваше объявление поля `_archive`:

```
private Boolean _archive = false;
        ^
```

И соответствующие методы `set`/`get`.

Comment: Спасибо, как раз так и сделал - по дефолту теперь false.